# Unable to build docker image, "must be a root user"

Tags: docker, dockerfile, expect

I am creating a Docker image by installing an application(should be a root user for installing) inside the container.

```
# cat Dockerfile 
FROM ubuntu:16.04
COPY $pwd/intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar /root/
COPY $pwd/login.exp /root/
WORKDIR /root/
RUN tar -xvf intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar 
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y expect \
                      expect-dev \
                      libxml2-utils
RUN whoami
RUN expect login.exp
```

Build process for docker image:

```
root@labadmin-VirtualBox:~/RAGHU/krishna# docker build -t release:4.0 .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  633.5MB
Step 1/8 : FROM ubuntu:16.04
 ---> 6a2f32de169d
Step 2/8 : COPY $pwd/intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar /root/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 36e9ea407082
Step 3/8 : COPY $pwd/login.exp /root/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 0fad538973d4
Step 4/8 : WORKDIR /root/
 ---> Using cache
 ---> f5d7f36bc37f
Step 5/8 : RUN tar -xvf intel_virtual_gateway_console64_1_9_0.tar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6cab428f1bc2
Step 6/8 : RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y expect                       expect-dev                       libxml2-utils
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 5bb1ee67332f
```

To confirm that the container is running as root user:

```
Step 7/8 : RUN whoami
 ---> Running in 112b87d77a08
root
 ---> 0c7eb38cc06b
Removing intermediate container 112b87d77a08
Step 8/8 : RUN expect login.exp
 ---> Running in 5f186baf2f8d
spawn ./virtualgatewayconsole_package/virtual_gateway_console_intel64
Install Error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
To install the application, you must be a root user.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Type any key to exit: ^C
```

Unable to find out why the application installation has failed even though it is run as root user.

**EDIT : ADDING login.exp script:** This script is so basic to get my functionality done.

```
#cat login.exp 
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

if 0 {
     *************************READ THIS BEFORE START*********************
     User password must consist of at least 3 of the following categories: 
     uppercase, lowercase, numeric, and non-alphanumeric. In case of violation
     of this rule the Installation will fail!
     ********************************************************************
     }
set passwd "ISHAAN@p2017"
set username "raghu"

spawn ./virtualgatewayconsole_package/virtual_gateway_console_intel64
expect "Press Enter key to continue or q to quit:" 
send "\n" 

expect "Press ENTER for more, or q when done"  
send "q" 

sleep 5
#expect "conditions of this license agreement?"
expect "*(accept/decline): "  
send "accept\n" 

#Product installation
expect "*Please type a selection \[1\]:" 
send "\n" 

expect "*Please type a selection (Press Enter to next):" 
send "\n" 

sleep 2
#Configure TLS settings
expect "*Enter TLS keystore password (only numbers, letters and !@#$%^*()_+{}|.:?=-):"
send $passwd
send "\n"

expect "*Retype TLS keystore password:"
send $passwd
send "\n"

sleep 2
expect "Please type a selection (Press Enter to next):"
send "\n"

#Configure host
expect "Please type a selection (Press Enter to next):"
send "\n"

expect "Please type a selection (Press Enter to next):"
send "\n"

#Configure user for logging on the management console
expect "Please type a selection (Press Enter to next):"
send "\n"

sleep 2
expect "Enter user password (only numbers, letters, spaces and !@#$%^*()_+{}|.:?=-):"
send $passwd
send "\n"

expect "Retype user password:"
send $passwd
send "\n"

expect "Please type a selection (Press Enter to next):"
send "\n"

sleep 2
#Configure PostgreSQL service
expect "Please type a selection (Press Enter to next):"
send "\n"

expect "Enter PostgreSQL user password (only numbers, letters and !@#$%^*()_+{}|.:?=-):"
send $passwd
send "\n"

expect "Retype PostgreSQL user password:"
send $passwd
send "\n"

expect "Please type a selection (Press Enter to next):" 
send "\n"

sleep 60
#Create Keystore
expect "What is your first and last name?"
send $username
send "\n"

expect "What is the name of your organizational unit?"
send "radisys"
send "\n"

expect "What is the name of your organization?"
send "radisys"
send "\n"

sleep 2
expect "What is the name of your City or Locality?"
send "banglore"
send "\n"

expect "What is the name of your State or Province?"
send "karnataka"
send "\n"

expect "What is the two-letter country code for this unit?"
send "IND"
send "\n"

sleep 2
expect "Is CN=raghu, OU=radisys, O=radisys, L=banglore, ST=karnataka, C=IND correct?"
send "yes"
send "\n"

sleep 2
expect "Please type a selection \[q\]:"
send "q"

expect eof
```

Comment: What's in `login.exp`?

Comment: Expect usually watches output for patterns to detect things it is looking for. Without seeing `login.exp` I would guess it is looking for a shell prompt pattern that it thinks means "root user" and it is not seeing that particular pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container version of root and the root you know on the host are not necessarily the same thing. The biggest difference is that docker removes various capabilities from the root user to prevent them from breaking out of the container, so the user doesn't have access to physical hardware devices where they could mount the harddrive directly inside the container, or adjust the cgroup settings to escape the namespace.

From the name of the file you're running, it looks like you're trying to install a KVM which will need to access the hardware. I don't think this is going to be the best use case for a container which is designed for portability and isolation from the hardware while this app is likely designed with hardware specific configuration and access as a key requirement.

While `docker build` doesn't allow hardware access, you could potentially use `docker run --privileged` to perform the install manually and then `docker commit` to save that container to an image. This is normally the last way you would want to build an image, but in this case, it may be the only way, assuming it's possible at all.